# mysql foreign keys multiple keys for an entry

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i want to do for a table something like this.
I have two tables one with a foreign key(id) and second table where i hold data that coresponds to the first table.
My problem is that for each entry i might have one or two even more groups that belongs too.
Is it posible to do something like this:
table1 - id(foreign key) table2 - entry1 - table1.id1, table1.id2
And if it is posible can you explain how should i do?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `network`.`dbo.networkNodes` (
  `nodeId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nodeName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nodeId`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `network`.`dbo.networkIps` (
  `networkIpId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nodeId` INT(11) NULL ,
  `networkIp` INT(20) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`networkIpId`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question by referencing the actual table names, instead of table1, table2?  It's confusing which table you mean where, since you use two names for each table.

Comment: table1( dbo.networkNodes ), table2( dbo.networkIps )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for either a many-to-many relationship, or multiple, defined one-to-many relationships, so it depends on the use.

A many-to-many relationship would actually require an intermediate table, containing an 'id' field pointing to each of the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE networkNodes (
    nodeId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nodeName varchar(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nodeId)
);

CREATE TABLE networkIps (
    networkIpId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    networkIp int(20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (networkIpId)
);

CREATE TABLE netowkNodesIps (
    nodeId int(11) NOT NULL,
    networkIpId int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nodeId, networkIpId)
);
```

If you would rather add multiple one-to-many relationships, the specific relationship 'reason' should be contained in the name of the foreign key.